# The header image of the bulletin is broken for some sites

Tags: bug, status-completed, newsletter, 404-not-found

I receive several community bulletins. Yesterday (Wednesday) I received those from [SOes](https://es.stackoverflow.com) and [Music Fans](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com) and noticed the image in the header points to a broken URL:

- `https://sstatic.stackoverflow.email/Sites/musicfans/Img/newsletter-header.png`

[image]

- `https://sstatic.stackoverflow.email/Sites/es/Img/newsletter-header.png`

[image: https://sstatic.stackoverflow.email/Sites/es/Img/newsletter-header.png]

So the email shows like this:

> [image]

However, on Stack Overflow's digest (Tuesday) the image reference works well, as it points to the working path [`https://sstatic.stackoverflow.email/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/newsletter-header.png`](https://sstatic.stackoverflow.email/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/newsletter-header.png).

Comment: The images are now broken...

Comment: We're looking into this. Thanks for raising.

Comment: @JonChan thanks! I don't understand, though, why the [meta-tag:status-deferred]. From the [tag info](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/status-deferred/info), _A feature request or bug with this tag is something that has been evaluated as positive on potential, but is not present in the current work timeline_

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' `status-deferred` for us means it's something worth addressing, in our backlog, but isn't being worked on in the short-term (a current or upcoming planned sprint). In other words, we plan on working on it, but without a specific timeline given what our priorities are in the moment. When it is, I plan on getting this updated to `status-planned`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** The issue should be fixed for real now. The fix is live in production, so please let us know if you still see broken images.

---

I just tried to fix this bug, but it appears to already have been fixed on both sites (screenshots below). Let me know if there are related issues!

[image: Picture of Music Fans site header]

[image: Picture of Spanish Language site header]

Comment: No, it does not. See the last bulletins I received over the last hours: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NBQ7.jpg and https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIfGY.jpg In the first case it points to https://sstatic.stackoverflow.email/Sites/philosophy/Img/newsletter-header.png, while the second to https://sstatic.stackoverflow.email/Sites/es/Img/newsletter-header.png Both do not exist

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' We did some more digging and found the issue... hopefully. Fix should be coming early next week.

Comment: The links in the question still lead to 404 errors. Do the emails now have different image URLs?

Comment: @AdamLear and Jane: thanks! I got new bulletins and all of them show the header perfectly.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' Awesome, thanks for confirming!