# The header "Confirm subscription" does not render in email

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown, email, tag-filters

I just updated a [tag filter](https://stackexchange.com/filters/) and got an email from Stack Exchange to confirm it:

> [image]

As seen, it has a header "confirm subscription" that does not properly render its header.

I checked emails from a couple of years ago and it showed properly:

> [image]

So it seems to be an issue related to the [We're switching to CommonMark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348746/209901).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Commonmark spec requires a space after the hashtags, so that broke once we switched over.

The fix is out in production. Thanks for the report!

Comment: Thanks. Maybe it is time to tackle [The header image of the bulletin is broken for some sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/346227/209901) also: one year with this bug in the newsletter looks bad.